# What is Widest Steiner Tree(WST)

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-algorithm

Recently, I read some papers about multicast routing Algorithms.For example, Shortest Path Tree(SPT),Steiner Tree(ST), Widest Shortest Path Tree(WSPT) and so on. It’s easy to define a widest path, but i am confused that what is the Widest Steiner Tree(WSPT) and how we define a widest tree.

Answer (score 0):

In a graph setting, a Steiner tree with respect to a set of terminal vertices is a subgraph that (1) is a tree (2) connects each pair of terminal vertices. The *widest* Steiner tree of a capacitated graph maximizes the minimum edge capacity in the tree.

Comment: One way is to compute a maximum spanning tree and delete all edges and nodes not needed to connect some pair of terminals. This is as wide as possible but may use more edges than necessary. Minimizing edges too is NP-hard I think.

Comment: Practically speaking, I'd use integer programming and generate cut covering constraints as needed.